# Impossible to join room with socket io 2.2.0

Tags: express, socket.io

I am trying to join a room with socket io :

```
  socket.join(to, async () => {
    console.log('ici')
      if (!room) return

      try {
          const user = await ChatRedis.getUser(room, username)
          await ChatRedis.setUser(room, username, { ...user, conference: to })
          console.log(admin
              ? `Conference - User "${username}" opened a conference`
              : `Conference - User "${username}" joined the "${to}" conference`)
          namespace.in(to).emit('joinConference', { username, to, room, from })
      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
      }
  })
```

But the callback version is not working. I am using workspace I do not know if it is the issue

Socket io version : 2.2.0

Express: 4.17.1

Comment: The newest versions of socket.io, no longer use a callback for `socket.join()`.  See the doc [here](https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-api/#socket-join-room).  I'm not sure what version they changed that in.

Comment: Yes I know  I am using the 2.2.0 not the version 3(should work with it) and after checking rooms in empty

Comment: When you say "is not working", what exactly do you mean?  Do you mean that the socket doesn't join the room or do you mean that the callback isn't called?  Have you stepped into the `socket.join()` call in the debugger to trace through and see exactly what is or isn't happening?

Comment: Also, what is this `if (!room) return`?  There's no `room` variable shown in this code.  And, what is `to` in `socket.join(to, ...)` and why is it different than `room`?  Basically, I'm asking to see a larger code context so I can see where these variables you're using come from.  Also, thinking you should `console.log()` them both to see if they are what you think they are.